# Unable to change thickbox width of WordPress front end but height can be changed

Tags: wordpress

I am using thickbox on the front end of WordPress. I am able to change the thickbox width on localhost but not in live site. I am aware of this link - https://codex.wordpress.org/Javascript_Reference/ThickBox

I have follow the official WordPress. Here is how I want to change the width of the thickbox:

```
<?php add_thickbox(); ?>
<div id="cspd_wc_wa_btn_link" style="display:none;">
    My thickbox content
</div>
<a href="#TB_inline?width=295&height=350&inlineId=cspd_wc_wa_btn_link" class="thickbox">Open thickbox</a>
```

It can change the height of the thickbox nicely, but it is not able to change the width. Please help.
And another thing to mention is that the problem is not found when I test it on localhost. The problem only occurs on the live site.

Comment: edit your question and show us some code...

Comment: Inspect it to see if it's been overwritten by css?

Comment: I have edited and you can see the complete code. I am only able to change height. But unable to change width. But if I test it on localhost, everything is okay.

Comment: Maybe thickbox is not a good option... I'll bet I'll use another option